# Выход программы из "спячки"

Tags: python, python-3.x

необходимо чтобы программа ровно в назначенное время прекращала выполнение цикла while, сейчас я делаю так:

```
import datetime
import time
import requests
while datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H%M%S') != '143400':
    requests.get('url')
    time.sleep(10)
#Выполнение операции print в 14:34:00
print('End')
```

Но проблема в том, что если time.sleep(10) будет вызвано, например, в 14:33:59 (позже чем за 10 секунд до конца) или request не успеет выполнится, то цикл станет бесконечным. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы любая операция прекращалась в назначенное время. Сайт на который подаются запросы не редко перегружен и из-за этого запросы выполняет долго.

Answer (score 1):

Проверять не точное время, а промежуток:

```
t = int (datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H%M%S'))
while t < 143350 or t > 143420:
    # здесь код
    t = int (datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H%M%S'))
```

Если текущее время - между 14:33:50 и 14:34:20, то цикл прекращается.

Comment: Можно было бы тогда уж `datetime.time` использовать

Answer (score 0):

> необходимо чтобы программа ровно в назначенное время прекращала
>   выполнение цикла while

Сильно подозреваю, что на самом деле, Вам нужно нечто совершенно иное. А именно:

Программа должна начать выполнение некоторого действия ровно в момент времени *time*

Так? Тогда Вам надо воспользоваться стандартной функцией:

> signal.alarm(time)
>
> ```
> If time is non-zero, this function requests that a SIGALRM signal be sent to the process in time seconds. Any previously scheduled alarm
> ```
>
> is canceled (only one alarm can be scheduled at any time). The
>   returned value is then the number of seconds before any previously set
>   alarm was to have been delivered. If time is zero, no alarm is
>   scheduled, and any scheduled alarm is canceled. If the return value is
>   zero, no alarm is currently scheduled. (See the Unix man page
>   alarm(2).) Availability: Unix.

Разумеется, перед этим вызовом нужно установить обработчик сигнала SIGALRM, который и запустит желаемое действие.

Comment: "Availability: Unix".  Решение доступно не для всех систем.